# subdomain creation problem dyamicaly in php

Tags: php

I have a function code to make subdomain dynamically by php.Code is below

```
<?php

define('CPANELUSER','username');
define('CPANELPASS','password');
define('CPANEL_SKIN','x3');
define('DOMAIN','www.abcd.com ');


$result = subd('localhost',2082,$cpaneluser,$cpanelpass,$request);

function subd($host,$port,$ownername,$passw,$request) {

  $sock = fsockopen('localhost',2082);

  if(!$sock) {    
    print('Socket error');
    exit();
  }
  // ...
```

This is working ok on my testing server.But when i transfer file to customer server this is not working. Customer server is "iPage" and i m getting an error "Socket error".I m not understating why this is error is occurring even this was working fine in previous server.And there are no any skin name is available in iPage too.Help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe your customer server's configuration disallows the usage of a socket connection. Use the debug parameters of fsockopen (http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) to get a clear image of what's going wrong. The error number and error string would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Strauberry is right. Nevertheless, it seems that you can use [Cpanel API](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/AutomationIntegration/) to perform such tasks.